# How can I create an HTML/CSS layout with rows and a dynamic number of columns

Tags: html, css

I have some data (a list) that I need to display in a layout with rows and columns. On my desktop I have room for it to have 5 columns, but my mobile device only has enough width for one column. How can I display this data so that if there isn't room for another column, the next item just starts a new row.

I tried using "float: left;" and it's very close to what I want, but when there isn't any more room and it starts the next row, I need the columns to still line up.

update: The problem with float:left; is that the items don't line up into columns. Since the items are user-editable I don't have any way of knowing ahead of time how wide they might be.

update2: Removed references to table and instead described what a table looks like.

This shows an example of how the markup is and what I have attempted. It also has a manually built table that shows what I'm trying to get it to do. 
http://jsfiddle.net/7rrcQ/

Comment: Please clarify: How does `float: left` fail to work? Maybe you need to set an equal width for the items. You could also consider using `display: inline-block`.

Comment: If you don't mean table, don't say table, it's confusing. Call it a layout or something

Comment: I do mean a table in the visual sense of the term, but I do not require it be a <table>. I updated my question to use the term layout with rows and columns to remove the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to line up in columns, then obviously for a column its elements must have always the same width. If you don't want to touch floated elements width, then you can wrap them in another div and then fix that div width.

Otherwise calculate dinamically with javascript floated element width and apply to them margins to line up with the column. But anyway you have to have in mind some column width, known a priory or calculated from first dynamically loaded element in that column.

If you want to adjust number of columns to the page width, then all column elements from all columns must have the same width if you want them to line up, because one element may be from a column or from another depending on the page width. If this width is in percentages, then there will be always same number of columns independently of the page width. In the other case (in pixel, em's), column elements will "jump" to the next row when page is gets more narrow.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you were looking for.. http://jsfiddle.net/7rrcQ/5/

```
<div class="newContainer">

            <div class="tdElement">Lorem</div>
            <div class="tdElement">ipsum</div>
            <div class="tdElement">dolor</div>
            <div class="tdElement">sit</div>
            <div class="tdElement">amet,</div>
            <div class="tdElement">consectetur</div>
            <div class="tdElement">adipiscing</div>
            <div class="tdElement">elit.</div>
</div>
```

Your Css

```
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.tdElement{
  border:1px solid black;
  float:left;
  width:100px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve the result without setting the items to a specific width (in some units). A table (whether in HTML or using `display: table` etc. in CSS) can get its column widths allocated by browsers according to the width requirements of the items, but then you need to have content divided in columns in a specific manner.

To make the amount of columns depend on the available total width, you would need scripting and guesswork.

If equal-width items are acceptable (and I don’t see why not) and if you can make a reasonable guess on the maximum width in `em` unit, you could use your current (`div` and `span` markup) and only the following style sheet:

```
.item {
   border: solid 1px;
   padding: 0 0.15em;
   float: left;
   width: 5.5em;
   text-align: right;
 }
```

The main problem is that adjacent borders won’t collapse. Sorry, I have no solution to that.